# Transition element not working in hamburger menu with tailwind css and nuxt/vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css

I am writing responsive navigation in nuxt3/vue

```
<template>
  <nav
    class="flex justify-between items-center w-[92%] mx-auto gap-4 border border-2 border-black p-2"
  >
    <div>
      <span class="text-xl">Javascript</span>
    </div>
    <div
      class="absolute md:relative p-4 left-0 bg-yellow-500 left-0 w-full top-[9%] md:top-[0%] transition-all duration-300"
      :class="{ hidden: isActive }"
    >
      <ul
        class="flex md:flex-row flex-col items-center gap-[4vw] justify-center text-xl"
      >
        <li>
          <NuxtLink> 1 </NuxtLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NuxtLink> 2 </NuxtLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NuxtLink> 3 </NuxtLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center text-center gap-4">
      <span class="flex items-center justify-center text-center text-xl"
        >Find us!
      </span>
      <div class="md:hidden cursor-pointer">
        <Icon
          @click="toggleMenu"
          :name="
            isActive
              ? 'material-symbols:format-list-bulleted-rounded'
              : 'material-symbols:close'
          "
          size="40px"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script setup>
import "animate.css";
import { ref } from "vue";
const isActive = ref(true);
function toggleMenu() {
  isActive.value = !isActive.value;
}
</script>
```

And the transition after clicking the menu icon doesnt work. I tried puttin this property of diffrent tags, i tried "animate.css"; can i use transition on display property or only on the opacity (tailwind creators i think thought of that)? can i use animate.css on this if not tailwind and why it didnt work? i want it to work smooth and be simple and clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No transitions happen on an element on the same render frame that its `display` property changes from or to `none`. If you still want some transition to happen, consider toggling between `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` to have the element not be interactable and interactable respectively. This then allows you to transition between `opacity` for example:

```js
const { ref } = Vue;

Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const isActive = ref(true);
    function toggleMenu() {
      isActive.value = !isActive.value;
    }
    
    return {
      isActive,
      toggleMenu,
    };
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.3.4/vue.global.prod.min.js" integrity="sha512-39BSQXI5q1XlvVhLfFRidKG8KM6Tr6VS/XSnNo6N/A0ZXexHCeoUI/s+ulujQy3UREjoLNrMnFat8VI0mMugWA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" integrity="sha512-c42qTSw/wPZ3/5LBzD+Bw5f7bSF2oxou6wEb+I/lqeaKV5FDIfMvvRp772y4jcJLKuGUOpbJMdg/BTl50fJYAw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav
    class="flex justify-between items-center w-[92%] mx-auto gap-4 border border-2 border-black p-2"
  >
    <div>
      <span class="text-xl">Javascript</span>
    </div>
    <div
      class="absolute md:relative p-4 left-0 bg-yellow-500 left-0 w-full top-[9%] md:top-[0%] transition-all duration-300"
      :class="{ 'invisible opacity-0': !isActive }"
    >
      <ul
        class="flex md:flex-row flex-col items-center gap-[4vw] justify-center text-xl"
      >
        <li>
          <a> 1 </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a> 2 </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a> 3 </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center text-center gap-4">
      <span class="flex items-center justify-center text-center text-xl"
        >Find us!
      </span>
      <div class="md:hidden cursor-pointer">
        <icon
          @click="toggleMenu"
          v-text="
            isActive
              ? 'material-symbols:format-list-bulleted-rounded'
              : 'material-symbols:close'
          "
          size="40px"
        ></icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

You could also consider using the [Vue built-in `<Transition>` component](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html) for removing/add elements into the DOM which would be a similar behavior to what `display: none` does:

```js
const { ref } = Vue;

Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const isActive = ref(true);
    function toggleMenu() {
      isActive.value = !isActive.value;
    }
    
    return {
      isActive,
      toggleMenu,
    };
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.3.4/vue.global.prod.min.js" integrity="sha512-39BSQXI5q1XlvVhLfFRidKG8KM6Tr6VS/XSnNo6N/A0ZXexHCeoUI/s+ulujQy3UREjoLNrMnFat8VI0mMugWA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" integrity="sha512-c42qTSw/wPZ3/5LBzD+Bw5f7bSF2oxou6wEb+I/lqeaKV5FDIfMvvRp772y4jcJLKuGUOpbJMdg/BTl50fJYAw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav
    class="flex justify-between items-center w-[92%] mx-auto gap-4 border border-2 border-black p-2"
  >
    <div>
      <span class="text-xl">Javascript</span>
    </div>
    <Transition
      enter-from-class="opacity-0"
      leave-to-class="opacity-0"
    >
      <div
        class="absolute md:relative p-4 left-0 bg-yellow-500 left-0 w-full top-[9%] md:top-[0%] transition-all duration-300"
        v-if="isActive"
      >
        <ul
          class="flex md:flex-row flex-col items-center gap-[4vw] justify-center text-xl"
        >
          <li>
            <a> 1 </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a> 2 </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a> 3 </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Transition>
    <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center text-center gap-4">
      <span class="flex items-center justify-center text-center text-xl"
        >Find us!
      </span>
      <div class="md:hidden cursor-pointer">
        <icon
          @click="toggleMenu"
          v-text="
            isActive
              ? 'material-symbols:format-list-bulleted-rounded'
              : 'material-symbols:close'
          "
          size="40px"
        ></icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```